# How can I suppress command from keyboard in Python?

Tags: python, keyboard

Is there any way to suppress up arrow press physically from keyboard other than do manually the reverse action?

Eg. up arrow press -> manually simulate down press key

Problem: I am trying to autocomplete some words and at up arrow press physically, if I am doing the reverse (simulate down key press) it goes to fully left in the current window. The only solution I see right now is to memorate the lengths of written words and press right key for total length number.

Comment: What? Why do you need this? Where is it used? Are you talking about suppressing key-presses in the operating system from Python? If so, you're in for a ride.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nvm, I found the answer in another thread:

@Torxed, yes it is related to key-press suppressing and I am using this to create an autocomplete tool.

```
from pynput import keyboard

def keyboard_listener():
    global key
    global keyboard_listener

    def on_press(key):
        print('on press', key)

    def on_release(key):
        print('on release', key)
        if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
            return False

    def win32_event_filter(msg, data):
        if(msg == 257 or msg == 256) and (data.vkCode == 38 or data.vkCode == 40):
            listener._suppress = True
        else:
            listener._suppress = False
        return True

    return  keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press, 
        on_release=on_release, 
        win32_event_filter=win32_event_filter,
        suppress=False
    )


listener = keyboard_listener()

if __name__== '__main__':
    with listener as ml:
        ml.join()
```

Comment: This seems to be a solution for Microsoft products